# Call to local method from list comprehension failing

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, list-comprehension

I am trying to use list comprehension that calls a local method as part of the qualifier. For some reason it seems to be failing and I can't tell why. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

List comprehension:

```
pids = [item[2] for item in parsed if self.is_number(item[2])]
```

Local method:

```
def is_number(s):
      try:
          float(s)
          return True
      except ValueError:
          return False
```

Data:

```
[['Group', 'Topic', 'Pid Offset', 'logSize', 'Lag', 'Owner'], ['group1', 'test', '0', '232820', '232820', '0', 'test_c5dbb5fe-065c-4d3b-9da5-ecbe1d4ff330'], ['group1', 'test', '1', '229936', '229936', '0', 'test_c5dbb5fe-065c-4d3b-9da5-ecbe1d4ff330'], ['group1', 'test', '2', '58317', '58317', '0', 'test_c5dbb5fe-065c-4d3b-9da5-ecbe1d4ff330']]
```

I know it's a complete hack. I plan on cleaning it up later. However, I want to see it running first. Can anyone help me figure out what the issue is?

Comment: You can check if a string is a number with `str.isdigit()`

Comment: @cricket_007I am new to python and was looking for just that and saw several s/o answers that said such an option did not exist. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Should this "method":

```
def is_number(s)
```

be

```
def is_number(self, s)
```

instead?

or, maybe,
the call inside the comprehension be:

```
is_number(item[2])
```

and not

```
self.is_number(item[2])
```

At @Paul_Rooney suggestion, a static method is likely the better option:

```
pids = [item[2] for item in parsed if cls.is_number(item[2])]
# cls being the name of the class containing the static method called

@staticmethod
def is_number(s):
    ....
```

Comment: Ugh. You got it! Your first suggestion was correct. I had tried the latter w/o success. Thank you.

Comment: or you could make it a `staticmethod`, seeing as it doesn't seem to be using any member variables. Also you could trim the first entry off your list, which seem to be the field names, by using `parsed[1:]`.

Answer (score 1):

The following code:

```
def is_number(s):
      try:
          float(s)
          return True
      except ValueError:
          return False

parsed = [['group1', 'test', '2', '58317', '58317', '0', 'test_c5dbb5fe-065c-4d3b-9da5-ecbe1d4ff330']]
pids = [item[2] for item in parsed if is_number(item[2])]

print(pids)
```

gives:

```
['2']
```

The OP makes it difficult to know if that's the expected output or not.